# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) is occuring some times

Tags: android, serversocket

I have searched a lot for this exception, which rarelly occur, but I didn't find any relevant answer which can solve my problem,
I am using `HttpURLConnection` to get response as a xml from a url, it works fine but sometimes i get this exception:
`java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)`,
I have used following code and url1 is my url which gives a xml.

```
url=new URL(url1);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);  
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String result, line = reader.readLine();
result = line;
           while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                       {
               result+=line;
           }

           System.out.println("Result: "+result);
```

Comment: have a connection time out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638634/android-how-to-set-a-http-connection-timeout-and-react-to-it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "SocketException : Connection reset by peer" in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207394/getting-socketexception-connection-reset-by-peer-in-android)

Answer (score 10):

Try put urlConnection.setRequestProperty("connection", "close"); before connecting. This will disable keep-alive property which is on by default

Comment: how to set this for HttpClient or HttpPost?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when trying to talk with my server. I'm still not sure what happened, but I found [this](http://blog.csdn.net/a859522265/article/details/7965971) in my search to resolve the issue:

> ok, the answer was that it's the server's fault - it had to close the
>   connection after each request . it might be that android keeps a pool
>   of connections and use the old one or something like that . anyway ,
>   now it works.

After reading this post, I killed the `apache` instance running on my server, let the phone see that the connection was refused, and restarted `apache`. After that, the issue disappeared. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i changed from **http** to **https** and everything became normal

Answer (score -1):

open your browser you are using and try copying the urland paste it into your browser of your MOBILE DEVICE , if you still get the same error or may be connection refused that means your MOBILE and YOUR PC on which server runs are not on the same plan.

Comment: Yes I did this thing but it is opening in browser of mobile, as i explained it is occuring 5 times out of 20 times tested.

Comment: No it doesn't. There can't be a connection to reset unless there was a connection, and there can't be a connection unless there was a network path between the peers.